# Problem with device: Can ping, cannot tftp put

Tags: networking, ping

I have a custom device with network. On the device I have tftp server. The device is connected directly to my pc by an ethernet cable. I know how the tftp server works - I have successfully tested it on another pc. I can ping my device, but the tftp transfer fails. I believe it fails because the pc doesn't get the message I see. The tftp translation  starts, but does not end properly.
What kind of cast is used for ping protocol: unicast or multicast?  If ping uses multicast, the problem is that my device appears to show a unicast message and I can't reach my pc.

Network settings:

device:

192.168.0.5 ip

255.255.255.0 mask

192.168.0.1 gateway

pc

192.168.0.1 ip

255.255.255.0 mask

(win default) gateway

wireshark sniff
https://yadi.sk/d/TEa230vKcErMjg?w=1

Comment: Do you know how to use tcpdump or wireshark? Ping will use unicast to send the icmp packets if you tell it to ping a particular address, but before that there will probably be a broadcast packet to discover the MAC address (ARP protocol), My initial thought is that this is not going to be a "cast" issue. Which tftp client are you using on the pc?

Comment: I use custom tftp, but i also have tried with default windows tftp and found no difference. On wireshark i see, that my pc send put file request of tftp translation, receive adknowledge, but not recognize it. Then, my pc just send put file request periodically until timedout. 
I added link on wireshark sniff to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The custom_tftp_client pcap file.

This shows a request to write a file with a very windows like filename

```
C:\Users\Ksandr\Desktop\IpAudioServer\firmware\forloader loader\reserver_firmware\forloader_reserve_0049496FB6AD.bin
```

The file is marked to be transferred in **netascii** mode, which is unusual for a **bin** file. The source port for the request is 51456. I would worry a little about the backslashes and the space in the filename although it is of course valid. The tftp client is also requesting a timeout of 5 and a tsize of 46732. The tftp server sends the ack, with the correct destination port (51456) and an ephemeral port (49153). The correct udp checksum is shown for the ack (incorrect ones are shown for the requests but this might be due to the NIC doing the checksum calculation).

The MAC address of the 192.168.0.5 is 00:49:49:6f:b6:ad so is a globally administered (the 2nd least significant bit of the first byte is zero) unicast (the least significant bit of the first byte is zero) address. It would probably be better to have the first byte be 02, to show it was locally administered unless of course your org has 00:49:49:xx:xx:xx deligated to you.

The tftp client repeats the request to port 69 with no further responses from the tftp server.

- The windows_tftp_client pcap file

This shows a request to transfer a file with a less controversial name

```
forloader_reserve_0049496FB6.bin
```

and it is being transferred as a **binary** (binary) file. The request is sent from port 62500 from 192.168.0.1 to port 69 on device 192.168.0.5. The ack goes back to the correct port, with an source port of 49153 and the correct udp checksum. The tftp client continues to repeat the request to port 69 after a sequence of delays of 1,2,4,8,8,8,8,8 seconds until it eventually sends a timeout message after 47 seconds.

- So what is wrong?

1. The tftp server on 192.168.0.5 ought to respond to more than one request, it is always possible that the ack that it sent was lost so the client is allowed to repeat the request.
2. Both tftp clients appear not to be getting the responses. As the two devices are connected directly with an ethernet cable we can rule out networking equipment. I suspect that the IP stack on the PC has some firewall rules and is dropping the response as the packet is coming from a port that it didn't send to. The edit to the question indicates that one of the tftp clients was the "windows tftp client". There are answers on other SE sites such as [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159791/windows-firewall-settings-to-receive-udp-and-pings) to explain how to fix windows udp firewall issues. Note that you don't know which port will be used by 192.168.0.5 so you need to enable all the udp port or disable the udp filtering (Sorry, I don't have a windows machine in front of me so I am quoting the other answer without testing it, I don't know what exactly you need to do in this case).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with windows firewall. After disabling of firewall all things  works fine.